# Does anyone know what kind of camera Gunner Stahl is using here?

Tags: point-and-shoot, 35mm, camera

It’s hard to tell, but im wondering what kind of point and shoot Gunner Stahl is using here.

[image]

It is taken from this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bPTmStTSi4&feature=youtu.be&t=1m0s)

Comment: have you seen the original youtube video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bPTmStTSi4&feature=youtu.be&t=1m0s i dont have sound right now

Answer (score 9):

There is higher res image [image]

From which you can gather that it is most likely Contax T2 Compact 35mm Camera. You can find it's image [here](http://camerapedia.wikia.com/wiki/Contax_T2) and [here](https://www.theanalogstory.com/specs-tech/).